# Hey, i'm trying to put 2 conditions in one if statement. One in Javascript and one in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to put 2 conditions in one if statement. One of the conditions must be written in javascript/jquery because I want to get the window size. I'm using WordPress and when is the category page and when the window size is less than 1024px I want to `display: none`.

```php
<?php
if (is_category()) { ?>
    <script>
        var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();
        console.log(screenWidth);

        if (screenWidth <= 1024) {
            jQuery(`<?php get_sidebar(); ?>`).css('display', 'none');
        }
    </script>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: have heard media query word in CSS?

Comment: What is not working with this solution?

Comment: you cannot say in css if(is_category()){}..as i wrote.i need 2 conditions..not one

Comment: i can see the whole content of the sidebar in the console...but when the screen is bigger than 1024px the sidebar still doesn't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this and it worked perfectly.

```
<?php get_sidebar() ?>
            <script>
                function setSideBar() {
                    var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();
                    if(screenWidth <= 1024){
                        jQuery('#widget').css('display', 'none');
                        console.log(jQuery('#widget'));
                    } else {
                        jQuery('#widget').css('display', 'block');
                    }
                }

                setSideBar();

                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                        console.log('test')
                        window.addEventListener("resize", setSideBar, false);
                });


            </script>
```

Comment: Congrats, but writing js code in php file is not a good practice in WordPress. That is why there is a function named wp_localize_script to pass php value to js files. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use CSS Media Queries to fix this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  // apply css for everything under 1024px
}
```

[More info on CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: And how to check is_category in PHP here?

Comment: @davidev you don't need to check if it's is_category, you could just apply the css to the category page template

Comment: @devidev, Jiankai Zheng is right you can just paste code after if condition you do not need to load js and all.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly pass php value to a javascript file using wp localize script. See the below example. Hope you understand the below code what i did here.

**functions.php**

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function manami_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'manami-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); 

    // localize script
    $localization = array(
        'isCat' => is_category()
    );   
    wp_localize_script( 'manami-script', 'myValue', $localization ); 


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'manami_scripts' );
```

And then go to the script file and paste the below code

**script.js**

```
(function($){
    'use strict';

     var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();
     console.log(screenWidth);
     console.log(myValue.isCat);

    if(myValue.isCat){  // when value is true
        if(screenWidth <= 1024){
            jQuery('#sidebar_wrap').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Note: Do not use `<?php echo get_sidebar(); ?>` in jQuery selector. Use any class or ID.

I just checked in my local website before put the code here. Hope you will enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is okay and should execute what you want to do.

However, I think the line in `JS` where you insert the `get_sidebar()` is wrong. You are starting `PHP` there and executing the `get_sidebar` function. You will need to echo the return value of that function.

```
jQuery(`<?php echo get_sidebar(); ?>`).css('display', 'none');
```

OR

```
jQuery(`<?= get_sidebar(); ?>`).css('display', 'none');
```